# C++ lambda lifecycle

Tags: c++, lambda

In the following code, what happens at runtime?

```
while ( ([]()->bool { return something(); })() ) {
    ...
}
```

1. The lambda instance is created only once and reused in subsequent iterations.
2. Every iteration creates a new instance, that is only used once.
3. None of the above (please explain).

Initially it seems obvious to me that it's re-created in every iteration, but I wonder if the compiler does some kind of optimization.

Comment: Isn't a lambda just syntax sugar for a function (just anonymous)?

Comment: @EdHeal essentially yes, but AFAIK, it's implemented as a callable object that has a lifecycle like any other object.

Comment: The compiler is likely to optimise a lambda like that out completely. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a couple of standard quotes, with my emphasis:

[[stmt.while]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.while#1)

> In the while statement the substatement is executed repeatedly until
>   the value of the condition ([stmt.select]) becomes false. **The test
>   takes place before each execution of the substatement**.

[[expr.prim.lambda]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#2)

> A lambda-expression is a prvalue whose result object is called the
>   closure object.

The above tells use that `([]()->bool { return something(); })()` is evaluated before every iteration. And that the sub-expression `[]()->bool { return something(); }` creates a prvalue. So it springs to life only during the evaluation of the full expression.

So the dry letter of the law would indicate it's a different object of the closure type that is constructed and destructed every time the condition is evaluated.

But compilers are not stupid. I believe that under the as-if rule it's more than likely to be optimized into a direct call to `something()`. That is because the construction and destruction of the lambda does not have observable side effects.

And if we indeed use a tool like the [godbolt online compiler viewer](https://godbolt.org/g/ttK8Eg), we see that GCC 7.2 at `-O1` will call the function directly. And so does Clang 5.0, but I had to crank optimizations to `-O2` for that to happen.

Comment: Couldn't be better explained.