# About PyQt lambda lifecycle

Tags: lambda, pyqt, lifecycle

I'm learning PyQt。
I got to know we can use lambda to pass parameter in a connect operation,like bellow:

```
self.actionspi.triggered.connect(lambda: self.update_interface_name(self.actionspi.text()))
```

then I'm curious about if the lifecycle of the anonymous lambda is exactly as the c++ lambda talked about in here([C++ lambda lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546111/c-lambda-lifecycle))

thx

Comment: TLDR: no, it isn't.